# Ошибка syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php

Добрый день! Получаю ошибку syntax error, unexpected T_STRING в строках

```
\Tinify\setKey($this->settings->tinypng_key);
$data['compressionsthismonth'] = \Tinify\compressionCount();
```

Может это быть из за того, что на хосте версия php 5.2?
Так как на локальном сервере все работает и стоит там php 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В версии PHP5.2 еще не реализованы [неймспейсы](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.rationale.php). Вам придется или обновить PHP или сильно извратиться с переименованием классов и функций.

P.S. Извиняюсь за неформат. Но. Вообще, версия 5.2 вышла так давно, что люди, родившиеся после его выхода, уже в школу ходят, и некоторые, скорее всего, уже начинают постигать азы программирования (*с какого класса информатика?*). Так что, это лично мое мнение, лучше обновлять как нибудь версию, чем код.

Comment: Так и думал, просто забыл как называется )

Comment: Подскажите, есть CMS которая сейчас работает на версии 5.2, если я обновлю до 5.6 или 7, код будет работать или что то прийдеться редактировать?

Comment: На сто процентов не могу гарантировать, но всё должно работать. PHP старается дердать обратную совместимость. Есть большая вероятность, что CMS запустится и на версии 7.X

Comment: На всякий случай пройдитесь по классам в CMS (если там есть классы) и посмотрите наличие ключевого слова `var`. Его лучше заменить на `public`, это устаревшее слово осталось еще с 4-й версии. Недавно наткнулся на такое в какой-то древней CMS.